# Git SSH public key fingerprint does not match with that on local machine

Tags: git, ssh, fingerprint

I’m trying to SSH into my github account. I added my public key to my github account and it showed the fingerprint as something like this

```
SHA256:aYqWu+zL3hIOWTEGvneI90fehVQt9kuGVN7ov8WlTk8
```

When I SSH to git, it rejects me with

```
permission denied(publickey)
```

then I run

```
SSH -v
```

and see my client offered public key as

```
RSA SHA256:aYqWu+zL3hIOWTEGvneI90fehVQt9kuGVN7ov8WlTk8 macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro.local
```

mine has extra username@host.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What command are you using to ssh to git?

Comment: ssh -T mygituser@github.com

Comment: You need to specify your private key with ssh -i /path/to/privatekey -T username@github.com

Comment: It didn’t work. I got the same inform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read GitHub's guide on connecting via SSH (https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey), it actually tells you NOT to connect using your username.

All connections, including those for remote URLs, must be made as the "git" user. If you try to connect with your GitHub username, it will fail:

```
$ ssh -T GITHUB-USERNAME@github.com
> Permission denied (publickey).
```

Instead, you should use `ssh -i /path/to/privatekey -T git@github.com` (you can leave you the `-i /path/to/privatekey` if you're using ssh-agent)

Upon successful authentication, you should get a message like this:
`Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: Here is my command I used to ssh to git: ````ssh -vT dungtinhhd123@github.com````. Can you be more specific in the comment part in my fingerprint on the local machine. Can I somehow make it disappear?

Comment: The macbookpro@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro.local? You don't need to make it disappear, that is normal. You should just ssh -vT git@github.com.

Comment: Thanks. It was my huge mistake.